Perfect сubes duos in a line
We have a set of integers:  1,2,3,.....304,305
I like to rearrange them in a fashion such that the sum of every adjacent two is a perfect cube.
For example if we lineup 1,7 together (1+7=8 -- Perfect cube) then we maybe able to continue that with 20 next:  1,7,20  (7+20=27 -- perfect cube) .... then we need to continue the chain: 1,7,20, 44  (20+44=64 perfect cube!) ...etc.... until we cover the whole list up to 305.
So far I came up wih this to get a set of duos:
Select[Subsets[Range[305], {2}], IntegerQ[CubeRoot[#[[1]] + #[[2]]]] &] // Short

{{1, 7}, {1, 26}, {1, 63}, {1, 124}, <<391>>,{252, 260}, {253, 259}, {254, 258}, {255, 257}}

But then how do we streamline them?
Part 2)  I like to solve this in a CIRCULAR pattern also....that arranged in a circle they satisfy the same condition.   I assume this is easy as if we solve part 1, then part 2 is just ensuring the last number in the set when added to the first number in the set generates a perfect cube.  That's the only additional condition!

As @evanb pointed out there is no Hamiltonian graph for 305.
Here we try to find Hamiltonian graphs for higher values.
I used a different approach than OP to find all possible pairs whish is faster.
Table[{m, 
   DeleteCases[
      Flatten[Table[
        IntegerPartitions[(n)^3, {2}, Range@m], {n, 1, (2 m - 1)^(
         1/3)}], 1], {x_, x_}] // Graph // HamiltonianGraphQ}, {m, 1, 
   500}];
Position[%, {_, True}]


{473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500}

So we have first Hamiltonian graph for m=473.
m = 473;
DeleteCases[
   Flatten[Table[
     IntegerPartitions[(n)^3, {2}, Range@m], {n, 1, (2 m - 1)^(1/3)}],
     1], {x_, x_}] // Graph;
List @@@ FindHamiltonianCycle[%][[1]]
Clear[m]


{{1,63},{63,449},{449,280},<<467>>,{125,387},{387,342},{342,1}}

Although there does not exist Hamiltonian cycle for m=305 a Hamiltonian path exists.
m = 305;
DeleteCases[
   Flatten[Table[
     IntegerPartitions[(n)^3, {2}, Range@m], {n, 1, (2 m - 1)^(1/3)}],
     1], {x_, x_}] // Graph;
FindHamiltonianPath[%] // Short


{222,290,53,163,180,36,28,<<291>>,171,45,298,214,129,87,256}

There are exactly three such paths:
m = 305;
DeleteCases[
   Flatten[Table[
     IntegerPartitions[(n)^3, {2}, Range@m], {n, 1, (2 m - 1)^(1/3)}],
     1], {x_, x_}] // Graph;
Short@FindHamiltonianPath[%, #, 256] & /@ {95, 186, 222}
Clear[m]


{{95,248,264,79,137,206,10,<<291>>,171,45,298,214,129,87,256},
{186,157,59,284,228,115,10,<<291>>,171,45,298,214,129,87,256},
{222,290,53,163,180,36,28,<<291>>,171,45,298,214,129,87,256}}

For which m does there exist a Hamiltonian path...
Table[{m, 
   DeleteCases[
      Flatten[Table[
        IntegerPartitions[(n)^3, {2}, Range@m], {n, 
         1, (2 m - 1)^(1/3)}], 1], {x_, x_}] // Graph // 
    FindHamiltonianPath}, {m, 1, 500}];
Position[%, {_, {__}}] // Flatten


{305,333,385,386,387,388,389,<<104>>,494,495,496,497,498,499,500}

We see than m=305 is the smallest one.

Ok @azerbajdzan  so a solution does exist for a streamline version, only a closed-loop does not exist...which is OK! I wasn't necessarily expecting it to. But for former I was, which you found. Will study this solution more, thanks!

Hi @azerbajdzan If I want to see up to which sets of numbers do have Hamiltonian Paths, say in a range of 300-1000, I would assume I need to put your logic in a loop and have it evaluate all? ...or in a SELECT function? ...

Nice , with the 3 paths which you updated......  My question is can we see for which other m-Ranges both the Cycles and Paths exist. Cycles you did already , but what about Paths...

@Steve237 I added code.

Hi @azerbajdzan   one more thing:  your first block of code indicates there is no hamiltonian path for 305 (and that they start from 473), but your third block shows there is indeed a path for 305 (which is using FindHamiltonianPath)....How is that so. Whats the diff.   Is there a diff between HamiltonianGraph and Path? I assume HamiltonianGraphQ is checking for HamiltonianCycles then?

@Steve237 There is no H. cycle for 305 but there is H. path for 305. HamiltonianGraphQ gives True if there exists cycle, if it gives False there is no cycle but it is inconclusive about existence of path.

Ok so there are no other Q functions for the existance of paths? ....I assume

Hi @azerbajdzan  I am trying to mimic your last code block using my original SELECT method as such:   Table[{m,
FindHamiltonianPath[
Graph[Select[Subsets[Range[m], {2}],
IntegerQ[CubeRoot[#[[1]] + #[[2]]]] &]]]} , {m, 300, 500}];
Position[%, {_, {__}}] // Flatten    --> it's not giving the same result as yours. Is there a logical error?

@Steve237 Copy properly it is Position[%, {_, {__}}].

Hi @azerbajdzan  it does have the underscore!!! in my Notebook! It just didnt copy here properly!   Try it out! Won't work....   This board cuts it off, lol, when pasted from Notebook, I tried it again..maybe a shortcut for something

Never mind, it worked fine!  Here's the kicker tho:  If you replace your range {m, 1, 500}  to another range, like {m, 500, 600} it will not work!  I suspect you need a tweak elsewhere..this is what had me believed my algo didn't work, however it was the Range issue.   Can I not modify your range for higher sets? results don't make sense.

And my last comment: In your section "There are exactly three such paths:"  you are actually passing in {95, 186, 222} ... aren't these supposed to be returned?  Not passed in?

As I suggested, all the paths for 305 share a single endpoint---256---which must be the sole degree-1 vertex!

Hi @evanb ...#1) Where was this suggested? ending in 256?  #2) The second last query above cannot use 256 as input, nor can it use the {95, 186, 222} as inputs.  Those are what we are trying to find.

I hadn't found 256 explicitly, but I have now edited my answer to explain what I meant by using VertexDegree.  For 305, the 256 node has degree 1, which corresponds to the fact that the only pair with 256 in it is {87, 256} (giving 7^3).  If you're going to visit every number, you must cross this edge because there is no other way to get to 256.  But since we only cross an edge once, we use it up, and therefore we must start or end on 256.

Ok cool @evanb  now i see that code...next what command can you enter to see all 3 paths that end in 256?  (for 305)

Thank you for this instructive answer: +1 :)

Using your
pairs = Select[Subsets[Range[305], {2}], IntegerQ[CubeRoot[#[[1]] + #[[2]]]] &];

we can construct the adjacency graph
graph = Graph[pairs]

and then ask
HamiltonianGraphQ[graph]
(* False *)

so finding a closed loop in the way you want is not possible.
Also,
degrees = VertexDegree[graph];

has exactly one 1 in it, so that number must be one of the endpoints a linear chain, if one exists.  We can find which number this corresponds to,
ends = Transpose[{Range[305], degrees}] // Select[1 == #[[2]] &]
(* {{256, 1}} *)

Since degree=1 means there is only one partner which when summed with 256 gives a cube, that number must start (or end) any HamiltonianPath.
To find a Hamiltonian path that reaches every possible point
paths = DeleteCases[
    Table[FindHamiltonianPath[graph, end, j],
          {end, ends[[All, 1]]},
          {j, Range[m]}],
{}, 2]

Then, Dimensions[path] == {1,3,305}.  1 because there is one fixed endpoint, 3 because 3 nodes can starting points, 305 because we're making a chain from 1 to 305.  The three example Hamiltonian paths are
{
{256,87,129,214,298,45,171,172,44,299,<<286>>,228,115,10,206,137,79,264,248,95},
{256,87,129,214,298,45,171,172,44,299,<<286>>,137,206,10,115,228,284,59,157,186},
{256,87,129,214,298,45,171,172,44,299,<<285>>,61,155,188,28,36,180,163,53,290,222}
}

Because we found only 1 mandatory endpoint for 305 by computing the degrees, the other end is free and we had to check.  If there are 2 mandatory endpoints we need only FindHamiltonianPath between those two points.  If there are more than 2 degree-1 vertices there are no Hamiltonian paths.
If there are 0 degree-1 vertices we'll be in the worst case, where both ends need to be varied.

The graph is not EulerianGraphQ too.

Sure, but EulerianGraphQ isn't relevant to whether it's possible to visit every node.

Yes, you are right, at first I misread OP question.
